# Regulate Internet usage on iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, applications

Is there a way to regulate Internet usage on iPhone 4S? I'm looking for a program that enables me to put a limit on the time spend online (on certain sites).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you want, but you could try any of the browsers which offer parental controls, such as [mobicip](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobicip-safe-browser/id299153586?mt=8).

[Here](http://content.mobicip.com/content/how-setup-parental-controls-iphone-ipod-touch) is a little how-to for setting up mobicip.

Answer (score 0):

Other then what @Thecafremo mentioned, I'm not aware of any internet browsers that build that in. It is not a native feature, and the problem is that iOS apps are sandboxed almost entirely from each other, ruling out the possibility of one app controlling how long another app (i.e. Safari) runs.